Azure Logic Apps - Variables Array
I am trying to make a Logic app to turn off multiple VMs on schedule, I already defined it in variable array but something is off..
SETUP:
Variable

Deallocate

But then after fail in history the deallocate path is this:
/subscriptions/05ca62a1-b441-4c33-839d-12bd2ef71641/resourcegroups/%7B%22vmName%22%3A%22Dev1%22%2C%22resourceGroup%22%3A%22rg1%22%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%7B%22vmName%22%3A%22Dev2%22%2C%22resourceGroup%22%3A%22rg2%22%7D/deallocate
Tried to edit the variable setup but no success

Sorry but what exactly is the problem?

Below design worked for me:

Then used parse json:

Parse Json Schema:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "resourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}

Then in Deallocate VM action, use Enter a custom value to get value from parse json:

Then :

Then same for VM name too:

Output:


Thank you @rithwikbojja that was actually working. Unfortunately now I am stuck with the Conditions where I wish to get an email on success or fail. The email sending is working but the condition always evaluate as failed.. Could you please maybe advise?

Gald that its working.

Try to open a new question with all the details, community will help.
